# Python files (EXE) slow with Kaspersky and AVG

Tags: python, pyinstaller, antivirus, kaspersky

After I generate the executable with pyinstaller --onefile file.py, when I run the EXE file, the antivirus runs this file very slowly. AVG scans the file when I run it; Kaspersky takes almost 30 seconds to open the file. If I disable the antivirus, these files runs in less than 1 second.

Is there any way to configure the antivirus not to scan the files in the Pycharm folder?

Thanks!

Comment: You should ask your antivirus provider instead

Comment: Try to add your EXE file to your antivirus exclusion list